# VB.NET: Use a Textbox to filter Data

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Here is my code:

```
Dim connectionString As String ="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=F:\ACCESS DATABASE\search.mdb"

Dim selectCommand As String
Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)

selectCommand = "select * from GH  WHERE (COURSE='BSIT')"
Me.dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, connection)
```

I want to know how to use a textbox to filter data. Because this code will have to enumerate all of the courses, and will need much buttons.

Comment: where's the rest of your code? Or do you want us to write that for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sure I understand the question correct. Try this

```
selectCommand = "select * from GH  WHERE (COURSE='" & TextBox1.Text & "')"
```

Also you need to avoid single quotes(') on the textbox.

Comment: Mark it as answer, if you got the solution.

Comment: Er, @Remou, is the caveate about the .Text property applicable in VB.NET, which is the programming environment here? It *is* relevant within Access/VBA, but I wouldn't assume it would be in VB.NET, as in VB6 and before, the .Text property was equivalent to the Access .Value property (so far as I understand VB forms programming).